Class attributes are initialized to undefined when updating tsconfig target from "es2017" to "ES2022"
new Class() syntax is different depending on tsconfig when updating from "es2017" to "ES2022".
class Test {
    a: number
    b: string
}

const c = new Test()

With a symple syntax like this in the old version of my tsconfig c would be just an empty object {}.
But after updating tsconfig to a never version, c now equals {a: undefined, b: undefined}.
And it kinda breaks all unit tests + some code logic like Object.assign in our large codebase.
Is there a way to disable this logic, so that c after calling new would be just an empty object as it was before? Can someone maybe tell what is the issue here, history, etc?
I need never version of tsconfig for other changes in the project.
My tsconfigs:
old:
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es2017",
        "module": "Node16",
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "moduleResolution": "node16",
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "types": ["jest", "node"],
        "outDir": "./dist",
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "strict": false,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    },
    "include": ["**/*.ts"]
}


new:
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES2022",
        "module": "ES2022",
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "types": ["jest", "node"],
        "outDir": "./dist",
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "strict": false,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    },
    "include": ["**/*.ts"]
}



This was added in typescript 3.7, as per documentation: "Declarations are always initialized to undefined, even if they have no initializer.". This is because Javascript now supports class fields and initializes them to undefined.
The proper behaviour is to have them initialize to undefined, but if needed, you can disable it by adding the useDefineForClassFields to your ts configs with the value set to false. The value is true by default starting at ES2022 (documentation)

It would probably be helpful to indicate why this is happening: it’s because JS now supports class fields and initializes them to undefined. The old TS behavior is the “wrong” thing
